# R merge two lists into one, drawing elements from each list alternatively

Tags: r

I want to merge two lists into one, drawing elements from each list alternatively

Example:

```
s1 <- list(1,2)
s2 <- list(3,4)
```

I do not want:

```
c(s1,s2)
```

Instead, I want

```
list(1,3,2,4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Map` append the corresponding `list` elements of 's1' and 's2' as a `list` and then with `do.call(c`, flatten the nested list to a list of depth 1.

```
do.call(c, Map(list, s1, s2))
```

---

Or another option is to `rbind` the `list` elements into a `matrix` and remove the `dim` attributes with `c`

```
c(rbind(s1, s2))
```

Comment: I have tested both versions with short lists. The second version with `rbind` is up to 6 times faster than the solution with `Map`. The `rbind` version is twice as fast as the rcpp code from thc. All versions create only shallow copies of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Rcpp solution just for fun:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List abc(List x1, List x2) {
  if(x1.size() != x2.size()) throw exception("lists must be same size");
  List new_list(x1.size()*2);
  for(size_t i=0; i<x1.size(); i++ ) {
    new_list[2*i] = x1[i];
    new_list[2*i+1] = x2[i];
  }
  return(new_list);
}
```

R:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("abc.cpp")
abc(s1,s2)

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 4
```